# Copy file to ouput directory and rename it in c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2015 C# project that has a link to some external file.

```
<None Include="..\File.data">
  <Link>File.data</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

I want to copy this file (if it has been modified) to the output directory (as the above msbuild statement would do), but also want to change its name (e.g. to "Sample.data").

Is there an easy way to do this with the builtin msbuild tasks?

Answer (score 13):

Not sure for 2015. But in 2017 you can simply rename the  tag.

```
<None Include="..\File.data">
 <Link>Sample.data</Link>
 <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inbuilt so far as making this simple in your included XML.  What you would have to do is specify a rename statement in the post build event.  It means you have to hard code the filename, but this would work.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293582.aspx